# How to add data to the list and display it in activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple list in android. But My application is not running. I don't have any errors. I don't know whats wrong. Can u please help me..
Here's the code:

```
package com.example.mylistactivity;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;


**MainActivity.java**
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListAdapter adapter = createAdapter();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
        /**
         * Creates and returns a list adapter for the current list activity
         * @return
         */
        protected ListAdapter createAdapter()
        {
            // Create some mock data
            String[] testValues = new String[] { "Test1","Test2","Test3" };

            // Create a simple array adapter (of type string) with the test values
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testValues);

            return adapter;
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code..Y my application is not running?

Comment: whats the id of your list view in activity_main.xml??

Comment: in my below post i just did the other function when you click the list item it will delete the clicked item in the list that's all you won't consider that if you need that one take it or otherwise just neglect it

Answer (score 0):

You should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after list item change.

Your code is a bit confused

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(createAdapter());
```

Comment: I should call it after calling setListAdapter?

Comment: No, you should call it after you change something to the list. But in your case the problem is another: you don't set the adapter to the list.

Comment: M calling built in list view: ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testValues);

Comment: You should create a ListView view and do setAdapter on it

Answer (score 0):

I made this list view for you and you can use this one for a example and use this And if you have any doubts on this listview comment me..

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
        private ListView listView;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String name : mStrings)
            {
                mListItems.add(name);
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);   


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                        long i) {
                    String name = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    MainActivity.this.adapter.remove(name);         
                }
            });
        }


        private String[] mStrings = { "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
                "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
                "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
                "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
                "Allgauer Emmentaler","Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
                "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
                "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
                "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
                "Allgauer Emmentaler" };
    }
```

And this one is the main layout for the activity.....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);In this satement, do i have create a layout for listViw1 or its built in? Also i couldn't follow tis function: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                    long i) {
                String name = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                MainActivity.this.adapter.remove(name);         
            }..........Can u please explain it to me?

Comment: why u wrote android2:id. Whats the use of android2 and what it is?